# Activity stream object structure

Tags: django, specifications, activity-streams

I am trying to understand the concepts behind the activity stream specification, specificity using the Django:

- [Django Activity Stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream)
- [Specification](http://activitystrea.ms/)

I have the following components:

- Medal (A model instance)
- User (Whom the medal will be awarded too)
- Verb

As I understand it one of the following should be the correct way to structure the data, but I am unsure which.

```
 - Actor (Medal)
 - Verb (awarded to)
 - Action Object (User)
```

Example: 2014 medal awarded to Lee

**OR**

```
 - Actor (User)
 - Verb (was awarded)
 - Action Object (Medal)
```

Example: Lee was awarded 2014 medal

**Additional question**
How would targets work into this data set?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this

Lee (`actor`)
was awarded (`verb`)
the medal (`action object`)

This form might be more useful for you to use in [Action Streams](https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/streams.html), which let you "follow" things that Lee does/are done to him

Comment: I don't have a Judge in this scenario, but something has to be an actor?

Comment: In that case you were on the right track with the second example you put in the question. You must always have an actor and a verb.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.. It is the way i was leaning in the end also. If you update your answer to match the comment, i will accept.